# Authors not showing properly on github repository after merge from Upstream

Tags: git, github

I updated from a master repository to my forked repository. I did that using simple commands.

```
git fetch upstream
git pull upstream master
git commit
git push
```

Now all the changes made by other contributors is shown as my own. How can I revert these changes to show correct contributors?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can check
[your environment](http://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles)

Example troublemakers

```sh
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Mathias Bynens"
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
git config --global user.name "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="mathias@mailinator.com"
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
git config --global user.email "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
```